# Add new view to existing nested view using jenkins-job-dsl

Tags: jenkins, cicd, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create a `freestyle job` in `Jenkins`, which I will be using to create views dynamically, under a `nested view`, currently I am in POC mode so tried it like this:

I added below `script` to the job and executed it:

```
nestedView('nested') {
    views{
        sectionedView('automated-view1') {
            sections {
                listView {
                    name('Build Jobs')
                    jobs {
                        regex(/project-A-.*/)
                    }
                    columns {
                        status()
                        weather()
                        name()
                        lastSuccess()
                        lastFailure()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this execution created a nested view, with a sectioned view inside:

[image]

further, for the second run I wanted to add another view to the same nested view, so *I changed the name of sectioned view and kept the nested view's name unchanged*, expecting, that it will add that new sectioned view to existing nested view, here is the script executed second run-

```
nestedView('nested') {
    views{
        sectionedView('automated-view2') {
            sections {
                listView {
                    name('Build Jobs')
                    jobs {
                        regex(/project-A-.*/)
                    }
                    columns {
                        status()
                        weather()
                        name()
                        lastSuccess()
                        lastFailure()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as a result, **instead of adding a new sectioned view it has overridden the already added view**, and only new sectioned view remained, and previous one is removed, like this:

[image]

**Can someone suggest what needs to be done to add the new view under nested view using dsl?**

Answer (score 0):

> instead of adding a new sectioned view it has overridden the already added view

If you use a Job with a [Build step "**`Process Job DSLs`**"](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/#plugin-content-getting-started), you need to set to "`Ignore`" the options:

- **Actions for removed jobs**
- **Action for removed views**
- **Action for removed config files**

That way, you have a chance to preserve what you created before, when running your script a second time with different parameters.

[image: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin@master/docs/images/build-step.png]

Comment: These values were already set, as suggested by you, but still instead of adding new views to the nested view, jenkins is just overriding complete nested view.

Comment: @VivekGupta I would advise *avoiding* nested views for that reason: way too easy to delete existing stuff. I prefer creating a separate view.

Comment: thats right, the issue is, we already have the home screen too cluttered as the tabbed views are spanning 4 rows, and it is expected to rise even more, so some kind of nesting/structuring was required, that was the whole idea to start this POC.

Comment: @VivekGupta That is why I have a List view as first level, and Delivery pipeline views as second level created with the DSL pipelines { component(...) }. Under the first level (which only displays the list of Delivery Pipeline Views), I create Freestylejobs, and the second level filters them.